# Passing path Parameters in Lambda Key Condition Expression

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, dynamodb-queries

I want to know how we can pass path Parameters in Lambda Key Condition Expression. I have a scenario where I will be passing device_id, start_date and end_date from my REST API gateway

REST API from API Gateway: **/device/{device_id}/start/{start_date}/end/{end_date}/events**

The request goes to a Lambda Function which will in-turn will return the results that i.e no. of events for that particular device.

I wrote the below scan function

Code Snippet for Scanning DynamoDB from Lambda:

```
  ean={ "#tm: "time", },
  pe="#tm"
  response = table.scan(
    FilterExpression=Attr('device_id').eq(event['pathParameters']['serial_number']),
    ProjectionExpression=pe,
    ExpressionAttributeNames=ean
    )
```

But when I do this the method response is empty [] but when I use 
Code Snippet to Query:

```
     response = table.query(
       KeyConditionExpression= Key('device_id').eq(16)
        )
```

It gives me the required response back, but instead of hard-coding the value I want to pass a event(['pathParameters'][device_id]) here. Can someone let me know how to do it.